# Non integral exponent for taylor expansion using sage

Tags: sage, taylor-series

This is my function

```
var('h,r')
f=r^2*arccos((r-h)/r)-(r-h)*sqrt(2*r*h-h^2)

taylor(f,h,0,3)
```

Result:

```
-1/5*sqrt(2)*h^(5/2)/sqrt(r) + 4/3*sqrt(2)*h^(3/2)*sqrt(r)
```

I expected an expression of the form ax^3+bx^2+cx+d but I got 5/2 and 3/2 as exponents for h. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially directly using Maxima, so

```
(%i11) display2d: false;

(%o11) false
(%i12) f:r^2*acos((r-h)/r)-(r-h)*sqrt(2*r*h-h^2);

(%o12) r^2*acos((r-h)/r)-(r-h)*sqrt(2*h*r-h^2)
(%i13) taylor(f,h,0,3);

(%o13) 4*sqrt(r)*sqrt(2)*h^(3/2)/3-sqrt(r)*sqrt(2)*h^(5/2)/(5*r)
```

Expanding around other points gives what we expect, so I guess this is some kind of bug (or undocumented feature) in Maxima.

```
(%i22) taylor(sqrt(x),x,0,5);

(%o22) +sqrt(x)
(%i23) powerseries(sqrt(x),x,0);

(%o23) sqrt(x)
```

Maybe they like [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)?  I've reported this at https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/2850/

Edit: Of course, there **is** the problem that the square root function is not particularly well-behaved at zero!  But still one would expect something else, I think.

Comment: The bottom line is that it is a bug? I am new to sage. What is Maxima?

Comment: Maxima is the open-source program Sage uses to do integration, limits, and (some) power series.  They say it isn't a bug - see the bug report.  And I think I agree, though I also think our documentation (and first, theirs) needs to be updated to indicate why this is an okay answer (basically, because such functions (non-analytic) don't really have a "Taylor" expansion in the usual sense but there is "something relevant" that can be returned.

Comment: I went through the whole discussion about the "bug". I do not believe it makes sense to have a function called taylor return a Laurent or Puisseux series. It would be more logical to have individual functions for each type of expansion rather than having a confusing name. In any case, the documentation needs a clear update and some sort of return value to indicate the fact that it's not a taylor series being returned so as to allow a programmer to take some appropriate action. I would rather have an error returned though.

Comment: Incidentally, we have a very related ticket in Sage itself at http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/6119

Comment: "I think that changing the .taylor() method so that it calls a suitably Taylor-only version of the .series() method is preferable, especially since the global name taylor() should really be kept." I agree with this statement. Thanks for your follow up!

Comment: Tarik: I'm not sure I agree with you here, but if you feel strongly about this you should write to the Maxima mailing list explaining what you think is the right thing to do. To me, this seems like an example where fixing or understanding a perceived bug should be done upstream (Maxima), rather than hacking around it downstream (in Sage).

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in two parts.

1. The program in Maxima is more general than might be implied by the name (taylor).
   In fact it returns other kinds of series when a taylor series does not exist. This includes Laurent series (negative exponents) and non-integer powers. Try, for example, taylor(sqrt(1/sin(x)),x,0,5).

This can be fixed by changing the name of the command to (say)  series().  Although there may still be a naming issue because there are other kinds of series in the world, and you might want (say) an asymptotic series of some kind.

2. The original poster and some commentary seems to suggest that Maxima should follow a strict discipline of doing only and exactly what is specified by the nature of the command.  And if the system cannot do what the command does, it should give an error message.  That's not really what Maxima does. For a very simple example, if you type f(3), and f is undefined, some systems might say "error, f is undefined".  Maxima returns f(3), because under the circumstances, f(3) is a reasonable result that might allow you to proceed further.  As a second example, integration of some form that Maxima does not know how to integrate results in a formula with an integral sign.  Not an error "can't integrate...".

A general comment:  if you are using Sage to access only the facilities in Maxima, you might find it convenient to just use Maxima, a computer algebra system with its own user interface wxmaxima and plotting routines etc.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning wxmaxima!